# Using the definition of $f$ is $O(g)$ proof:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, asymptotics

I'm studying for my discrete math class and I don't understand how to prove big O notation. I understand that $f$ is $O(g)$ of another if $f(x) \le c g(x)$ holds.

1. How would I go about proving $\sin x$ is $O(1)$ using the definition.
2. Also how do you disprove? Suppose you're asked to disprove that $\frac {x^3+x} {x+1}$ is not $O(x)$ using the definition?

Can you show me the steps and explain why each step was applied in simple terms?

EDIT:  How would you do a question like this $e^x$ is not $O(x^5)$ Big O or/and $1$ is not $O(1/x)$.

Comment: Anyway, $\sin x \le 2 \cdot 1$, so taking $c=2$ will be enough.

Comment: @Crostul Also would I be able to take c=1? and is that all you would show to get full marks on a test..?

Comment: @Newbie: That's correct, you may take $c=1$ in that question. Note, though, that the second one does not make sense: disprove that $\frac {x^3+x} {x+1}$... what?

Comment: @AlexM. Sorry I meant to say show that x^3+x / x+1 is not O(x). Brain fart lol.

Comment: Assume it is...

Comment: @RickSanchez Yeah I know you assume that it is, but if you have to show that it is not O(x), how do you go about that?

Comment: Assume that it is $O(x)$, then derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a), simply take $c=1$. Anyway, any constant larger than $1$ is okay.

For b), suppose by contradiction that there exists $C>0$ such that $$\frac{x^3+x}{x+1} \le C x$$
Multiplying by $1/x$ gets you
$$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} \le C $$
But this implies that $\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}$ is bounded, contradicting
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2+1}{x+1} = + \infty$$

Comment: Is this because it is f(x)/g(x)? I somewhat understand. Suppose you wrote exactly that to answer a question on a test, would you receive full marks or would you have to be a bit more thorough with showing your proof?

Comment: I would give a full mark for such an answer.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much for your help. I figured out the rest of the practice questions but there's one that I can't figure out. Using the definition I have to proof that e^x is not O(x^5).  ---- So far I just wrote suppose e^x = O(x^5) Then there exists constant C such that for all large x we have e^x <= c*x^5. However e^x/x^5 approaches infinity so it is a contradiction. Is this correct? And where do I go on from here?

Comment: @Newbie Yes, your proof that $e^x$ is not $O(x^5)$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, in general, $\sin x \le 1 = 1 \cdot 1$, so it is trivial to understand that $\sin x$ is $O(1)$ where $c=1$.

For the second, assume that there exist $c>0$ such that $\frac {x^3 + x} {x+1} \le cx$; usually these problems are given for $x>0$, so your assumption would be equivalent to $x^3+x \le cx^2 + c$, or $x^3 - cx^2 + x - c \le 0$, but this is clearly false because that 3rd degree polynomial tends to $\infty$ (which is positive) for $x \to \infty$. Hence, the assumption is false.

Comment: equivalent to x3+x≤cx2+cx3+x≤cx2+c, or x3−cx2+x−c≤0x3−cx2+x−c≤0,  I don't understand this. And I need steps to proof it so that I will receive full marks on a test.